# Is this a valid diffeomorphism of $SU(3)$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, matrix-calculus, diffeomorphism

The map in question is $f: e^{\theta^IT_I}\rightarrow e^{M^I_J\theta^JT_I}$, for $M$ an invertible $8\times 8$ matrix and $T_I$ the half Gell-Mann matrices which generate $SU(3)$. My reasoning is as follows:

The map $\theta^I \rightarrow M^I_J\theta^J$ is smooth and invertible with smooth inverse.

The map $\theta^I \rightarrow e^{\theta^IT_I}$ is smooth and invertible with smooth inverse.

Hence, the map $f$ is a diffeomorphism of $SU(3)$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: No, your reasoning is incorrect. What you wrote for $f$ is not even a well-defined map (since the exponential map for $SU(3)$ is not 1-1).

Comment: Isn't $SU(3)$ compact and simply connected though? Therefore, doesn't that make the exponential map 1-1?

Comment: Yes, it is compact and is simply connected. However, such groups (unless they are trivial) never have injective exponential maps.

Comment: The thing to know is that for every compact connected Lie group $G$ the exponential map $\exp: {\mathfrak g}\to G$ is **surjective** (onto). If this map were also injective, it would be a homeomorphism. But ${\mathfrak g}$ is a real vector space, hence, cannot be compact (unless it is zero). On the other hand, $G$ is compact. Hence, $\exp$ cannot be injective.

Comment: What about when this map is well-defined? For example, if we take the map $f(A)=\bar{A}$, this is a diffeomorphism of $SU(3)$ and can be represented in the above way via some matrix $M$ which would basically be a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm 1$ depending on whether the corresponding GM matrix is symmetric or antisymmetric under complex conjugation. If we do this the other way around, i.e. find some $M$ such that the map is well-defined, would this $f$ be a valid diffeomorphism?

Comment: I have no idea what your last question means: If you find just one matrix $M$ for which $f$ is well-defined (how?) then the map $f: \{M\}\to \{f(M)\}$ of course is a diffeomorphism from a singleton to a singleton. For now, I am voting to close this question as ill-posed.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. The matrix $M$ given in my original question is what defines the map. If we find such an $M$ for which the corresponding $f$ is a well-defined map on $SU(3)$, is it a diffeomorphism?

Comment: I see. You still do not have a valid question until you find some "interesting" (say, not the identity) matrices $M$ for which the map is well-defined.

Comment: The question is valid. Given an $M$ such that the map is well defined, is it necessarily a diffeomorphism? Also, as I said earlier, the map $f(A)=\bar{A}$ can be written in the form in the original question for a non-identity $M$, so that's one example.